# git log submodule after changing folder structure

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-log

A git submodule was changed location in our folder structure in the module containing it by means of `git mv` (I think). Anyhow, when I ask for the history of the revision changes in this submodule from the containing module (`git log <submodule>`), the history stops at the commit bringing this change in folder structure about.

Can I ask git to continue tracing the changes related to this submodule through its change of location in the structure ?

Comment: Try  [`git log --follow`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-log%5D+follow).

Comment: Thank you for this, sadly no particular effect ...

Comment: (What's the policy here, do you deserve an upvote for a relevant though ultimately unproductive answer ?)

Comment: I don't think there is a strict policy. And I don't think unproductive comments deserve an upvote. :-)

Comment: I'll come back here and upvote you the day I end up using this flag then. Who knows, it may yet happen ! I do wonder if this folder structure change was done some wrong way which breaks the continuity of the history. Anyway I can see that ?

Comment: The recommended way in Git is to move/rename a file in one commit and change the file in another. But that's about files. Not sure about directories, probably the advice is the same. Even less sure about submodules.